# Tortoise "out of date" commit error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a new folder and I did a "checkup" and I got all my files from the repository. After that, I put in trunk file a new file(`file.R`) and do an "update" . Everything seems to be fine but when I am trying to commit the file I get the following error:

`Commit failed (details follow): File 'C:\trunk\example.R' is out of date Path '/"path"/example.R' already exists You have to update your working copy first.`

It doesn't make sense because it is a new file so it is updated. Can anyone help me? I am on Windows, with TortoiseSVN 1.9.1

Comment: Are you the only user? What revision is your working copy at? What does log reveal?

Comment: Hi @geo_dd, you just deleted your question on Programmers (correctly, this was off topic over there). Anyway Here the solution if you still need it:

Comment: Question is off topic. Anyway: You can use the modulo operator to check if a number can be divided by two (or any other number). This alone won't solve your problem (would work to get every second element). So what you do in your case is subtract one and divide by two (sample results: 1 or 2=0, 3 or 4 = 1, 5 or 6 = 2... call that group_index) Now you have grouped it and want to take every second 'group' so you just apply modulo on this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use SVN|TSVN 1.9.* for now - 1.9 now is buggy!** Downgrade to 1.8

Comment: Thanks for your advise!The version was the problem!!